# DragDrop between 2 listboxes which contain objects (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have **2 listboxes** which contain items of a specific class( with the usage of DisplayMember).
Now I want to implement **Drag and Drop** between these 2 listboxes.
At the moment I have no idea, how to implement the DragDrop event.
If I would only use strings, my code would look like this (for one listbox)

```
private void listBoxRight_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
            {
                Object item = (object)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
                string str = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
                int index = m_listBoxRight.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
                m_listBoxRight.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

This works fine. But how would be the implementation for real objects? Is it possible to implement drag and drop for any objjects?

Comment: Drag and Drop is meant for communication between 2 different processes. That is, a way to package/unpackage data in a generic way. But since you are wanting to implement drag and drop from and to your own process, you don't need to follow the generic package/unpackage of data (since you have access to both source and destination).